# Page with Symbols and Notation

Tags: arrays

I want to make a section for symbols and special notation, which should look like this:

[image]

What would you suggest in doing this? Should I just do like a table and create an array of 3 columns?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could use the [glossaries](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/glossaries) package; a little example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\newglossary{symbols}{sym}{sbl}{List of Abbreviations and Symbols}
\makeglossary

\newglossaryentry{fn}{type=symbols,name={\ensuremath{F_n}},sort=fn,
description={Empirical (sample) distribution function}}
\newglossaryentry{fncon}{type=symbols,name={\ensuremath{F^{n^\ast}}},sort=fnc,
description={$n$-fold convolution of the distribution function/distribution $F$}}

\begin{document}

\gls{fn}

\gls{fncon}

\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

[image]

The document must be processed using, for example, `(pdf)latex + makeglossaries + (pdf)latex`. Refer to the package documentation to see all the possibilities it offers.

Comment: what's the difference between a nomenclature and a glossary?

Comment: @pluton: A nomenclature, like, for example, a list of acronyms, can be considered a special case of a glossary. The `glossaries` package provides generic function for different types of "list of things" and references to them, in contrast to single-purpose packages like, for example, `acronym` or `nomentbl`.

Comment: How do I mark the entries in the glossar? do I put \gls{fn} in the line where I have F_n?

Comment: @Chris I don't understand what you mean with "mark the entries". Please explain with more detail.

Comment: Well, I have to tell latex where the symbol is in my source code. Do I tag it by putting \gls{name} in the code line where this symbol arises?

Comment: @Chris yes; you declare the symbols using `\newglossaryentry` (as in my example), and then in your document you use `\gls{<name>}` (or the other various available commands (see the package documentation)) to refer to the symbol.

Comment: @Gonzalo Medina Could you explain what `sort` means, like `sort=fn` and `sort=fnc`? And how do I give `sort` for other entries? Can I just don't give `sort` for them? Does it work in `amsbook` documentclass (I use it but now it doesn't work)? I'm using texstudio on Mac.

Answer (score 11):

Is it a nomenclature? Then you can use `nomentbl` package  for this.

A MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[intoc]{nomentbl}
\makenomenclature
\renewcommand{\nomname}{List of Abbreviations and Symbols}
\renewcommand{\nompreamble}{Following symbols are used in the present work:}
\setlength{\nomitemsep}{-\parsep}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\printnomenclature
\clearpage
\phantomsection
This is $F$\label{nomen:F} \nomenclature[EF]{$F$}{Objective function}{}{\pageref{nomen:F}}
\clearpage
\newpage
\phantomsection
This is $ND\_SNK$\label{nomen:ND} \nomenclature[EN]{$ND\_SNK$}{Total number of load buses in sink area}{}{\pageref{nomen:ND}}
\newpage
\phantomsection
This is $P_{Gi}$\label{nomen:Gi} \nomenclature[EP]{$P_{Gi}$}{Real power generation at bus $i$}{MW}{\pageref{nomen:Gi}}

\end{document}
```

By using a label and `hyperref` the page numbers can be turned into clickage links.

[image]

This has to be compiled with `pdflatex`. And then, you have to run `makeindex.exe -s nomentbl.ist -t "doi.nlg" -o "doi.nls" "doi.nlo"`, where `doi` is the name of your .tex (doi.tex) file. And, agian you have to run `pdflatex on`doi.tex`.

Comment: Perhaps you meant `nomentbl` or `nomencl`? (I didn't find any `nomentable` package on CTAN).

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: yes, it is `nomentbl`. I have corrected it. Thanks

Comment: @Harish Kumar: I copied your example and the output is the same as what you displayed. However, the hyperlinks all points towards first page. Do you know what might cause this behaviour? Did they work for you?

Comment: @AlfredM. You have to use a (phantom)section. I have updated the code. Pl, try now.

Comment: @Harish Kumar:works well with the sections. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple way:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{p{1.75cm}p{10cm}p{1cm}}
$N(\mu, \sum)$ & multivariate Gaussian (normal) distribution with mean   vector $\mu$
and covariance matrix $\sum$ & $1$\\
$M_n$ & maximum of $X_1$, $X_2$, \ldots, $X_n$ & $14$\\
$I_A$ & indicator function of the set $A$ & $175$\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

The arguments like p{1.75cm} tell you how wide the column is. If the information is too long, as in the first line (2nd column), it overflows to the second line.

Comment: Introducing the page numbers by hand is error-prone.

Comment: From the 2nd question of the post I thought the problem to be solved was the dramatic difference in the spacing of the columns and the fact that some descriptions continued to the next line.

Comment: The page numbers can be inserted with \pageref.