# Generating a nomenclature using nomentbl

Tags: nomenclature

I am trying to generate a nomenclature using `nomentbl` package. I found an interesting method written by user11232 in [Page with Symbols and Notation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54720/page-with-symbols-and-notation). The code reads as follows

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[intoc]{nomentbl}
\makenomenclature
\renewcommand{\nomname}{List of Abbreviations and Symbols}
\renewcommand{\nompreamble}{Following symbols are used in the present work:}
\setlength{\nomitemsep}{-\parsep}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\printnomenclature
\clearpage
\phantomsection
This is $F$\label{nomen:F} \nomenclature[EF]{$F$}{Objective function}{}{\pageref{nomen:F}}
\clearpage
\newpage
\phantomsection
This is $ND\_SNK$\label{nomen:ND} \nomenclature[EN]{$ND\_SNK$}{Total number of load buses in sink area}{}{\pageref{nomen:ND}}
\newpage
\phantomsection
This is $P_{Gi}$\label{nomen:Gi} \nomenclature[EP]{$P_{Gi}$}{Real power generation at bus $i$}{MW}{\pageref{nomen:Gi}}

\end{document}
```

I was instructed to first compile it with `pdflatex`, then run `makeindex.exe -s nomentbl.ist -t "doi.nlg" -o "doi.nls" "doi.nlo"`. So I added a new processing tool for TeXworks as follows,

[image]

I then ran my tex file "doi.tex" using "makeindex" but the following console output showed up:

```
Expected -s <stylefile>
Usage: makeindex [-ilqrcg] [-s sty] [-o ind] [-t log] [-p num] [idx0 idx1 ...]
```

Any help to fix this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The configuration window should be like the following one (one “word” per line). Add a new tool, don't modify the one for Makeindex.

[image]

Comment: Much appreciated for your kind answer. Unfortunately the console output still says `Couldn't find input index file doi,nlo nor doi,nlo.idx.`
`Usage: makeindex [-ilqrcg] [-s sty] [-o ind] [-t log] [-p num] [idx0 idx1 ...] `

Comment: @James You have a comma instead of a period somewhere

Comment: Indeed...... thank you so much, greatly appreciated !!